# Redux crashes when on new route and says TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

My app crashes and shows an error each time i try to go to `/users/create` however the error it’s showing is coming from a different file entirely which renders when i’m looking at a specific user and it has no issues there. It renders fine. The new route that I’m trying to create is so far blank with just text.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import "./styles.css";

import { editUser } from "../../actions/users";

class User extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: this.props.user,
      showEdit: false
    };
  }

  getUser = name => {
    const { users } = this.props;
    return users.filter(user => user.name === name);
  };

  handleChangeUserInput = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      user: {
        ...state.user,
        name: value
      }
    }));
  };

  isGroupAssigned = group => {
    const { groups } = this.state.user;
    return groups.indexOf(group) !== -1;
  };

  doesUserHaveGroup = group => {
    const { groups } = this.state.user;
    return !!groups.filter(g => g.id === group.id).length;
  };

  handleGroupChange = (e, group) => {
    const { checked } = e.target;
    if (checked) {
      this.addGroupToUser(group);
    } else {
      this.removeGroupFromUser(group);
    }
  };

  removeGroupFromUser = (group = "") => {
    const { groups } = this.state.user;
    // const idx = groups.indexOf(group.id);
    const idx = groups.indexOf(groups.find(grp => grp.id === group.id));

    if (idx !== -1) {
      this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        user: {
          ...state.user,
          groups: [...groups.slice(0, idx), ...groups.slice(idx + 1)]
        }
      }));
    }
  };

  addGroupToUser = (group = "") => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      user: {
        ...state.user,
        groups: [...state.user.groups, group]
      }
    }));
  };

  onShow = e => {
    this.setState({ showEdit: !this.state.showEdit });
  };

  editUser = () => {
    if (this.state.user.name !== "") {
      const idx = this.props.users.indexOf(this.props.user);
      this.props.editUser(idx, this.state.user);
      this.props.history.push("/users");
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { user, groups } = this.props;
    const { showEdit } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Link to="/users" style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}>
            <h3>
              <i className="fas fa-arrow-left" /> Back to users
            </h3>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="userWrapper">
          {
            <div>
              <h1>{user.name}</h1>

              <div>
                <label>
                  {user.name} has been assigned to the following groups:
                </label>
                <div className="card-columns">
                  {user.groups &&
                    user.groups.map((group, i) => (
                      <div key={i} className="card">
                        <label>
                          {groups.find(grp => grp.id === group.id).name}
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr />
              <div>
                <h3>
                  Edit{" "}
                  <i
                    onClick={this.onShow}
                    className="fas fa-sort-down"
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  />
                </h3>
                {showEdit ? (
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Name:</label>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      style={{ width: "400px" }}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeUserInput}
                      value={this.state.user.name}
                    />

                    <div>
                      <h4>Assigned Groups:</h4>
                      {groups.length > 0 ? (
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="columns">
                            {groups.map((group, i) => (
                              <div
                                key={i}
                                className="groupChoice text-center col-md-4"
                              >
                                <label>{group.name}</label>
                                <br />
                                <input
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  onChange={e =>
                                    this.handleGroupChange(e, group)
                                  }
                                  defaultChecked={this.doesUserHaveGroup(group)}
                                />
                              </div>
                            ))}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      ) : (
                        <div>
                          <p>
                            Sorry... currently there are no groups to assign
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <button
                        className="btn btn-success"
                        style={{ padding: 8 }}
                        onClick={this.editUser}
                      >
                        Save
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ) : null}
              </div>
            </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const getUser = (name, users) => {
  return users.filter(user => user.name === name);
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    users: state.users,
    user: getUser(ownProps.match.params.name, state.users)[0],
    groups: state.groups
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  editUser: (idx, editedUser) => dispatch(editUser(idx, editedUser))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(User);
```

I don’t know what is happening but research seems to indicate its from my store so here is my `store.js`

```
import { createStore, compose } from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducers";

const middlewares = [];

if (window.devToolsExtension) {
  middlewares.push(window.devToolsExtension());
}

const store = createStore(reducer, compose(...middlewares));

export default store;
```

any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: usually react will tell you what line has the error, my guess is `{groups.find(grp => grp.id === group.id).name}` , it can't find the `goup` so it's `undefined` and you're trying to access it's `name`

Comment: it says the error comes from    `{user.name}`

Comment: in `getUser` you have `const { users } = this.props;` and in render it's `{user} = this.props` , do you have `user` and `users` in the `props` ?

Comment: yes but the issue isn’t in the file. its redux thing that makes it crash when going to whole other route

Comment: Do you fetch the array of users async? If so, check if users are there before trying to filter in your getUser method.

Comment: @Mukeyii how do i do that

Comment: With if statements? if(users && users.length>=0) {...return users.filter } else { return default stuff }

Comment: Im Stil confused but thanks for trying

Answer (score 0):

"Map state to props" should exactly do what its name indicates: *Map the state values to your components props* ***(and nothing else)*.** Keep it pure and synchronous as stated in the docs:

> Much like a Redux reducer, a mapStateToProps function should always be
>   100% pure and synchronous. It should simply take state (and ownProps)
>   as arguments, and return the data the component needs as props. [[Source]](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/using-react-redux/connect-extracting-data-with-mapStateToProps.md)

I guess that you do an async call to fetch the array of users. You do filter in the same step without checking whether your list is empty or maybe even null. You could:

- Use an **action creator** to filter your users array in order to return a specific user.
- Extend your API and define a second **endpoint to fetch a single user** based on your criteria.
- Make use of your **getUser()**-method which you've defined in your component. In this case, check if the array is not empty || null.

Comment: how do i go about do in so? and just to be clear, so there is nothing wrong with my redux setup/store? cause again this error pops up on a different route when trying to render a completely different component.

Comment: It doesnt matter on which route you are. If you do update a store attribute which is used by a component or connected to it, you will enforce a rerender. And then your component will try to access specific store attributes which aren't loaded yet. Check the method "shouldComponentUpdate" and avoid rerendering, if it isn't the current & visible route.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it worked when i simply rearranged my routes in App.js to make the dynamic ones go last.